# Swift typealias for enum case

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, enums, type-alias

Alright, I've done my homework and read what I could find but I can't seem to find if this is possible to accomplish with Swift. I've got an enum that I use all over the place: `SomeEnum` and one if it's `case`s is a lengthy `SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName` and I'm tired of seeing it all over my code. I don't want to refactor because I like the descriptive nature of the case for when newcomer's maintain my code.

So here's the question: Is it possible to create a `typealias` for `SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName`? And if so, how? Here's what I've tried:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case SomeLengthyCaseName
}

typealias SLCN = SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName
```

That's the syntax but Xcode gives a compiler error saying that "`SomeLenghtyCaseName` is not a member of `SomeEnum`."

Ready, set, go!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a [misleading error message](https://bugreport.apple.com).

The real problem is that `SomeLengthyCaseName` is ***not a type***. Therefore you can't use `typealias`, which is only for aliases of *types*. (For example, you could say `typealias SE = SomeEnum`.)

Instead, you can just use a global constant:

```
let SLCN = SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName
```

Or, better, a static constant on the enum itself:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case SomeLengthyCaseName
    static let SLCN = SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName
}

let x: SomeEnum = .SLCN
```

Comment: Ah! Face palm! I don't know why I didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing that out. And thanks for the alternate solutions. I like the second because it's not a mystery where the "alias" came from. I'll accept as soon as the buffer is over.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible since `SomeEnum.SomeLengthyCaseName` is not a type, it's a value for the `SomeEnum` type.